# Force a specific scroll distance for various scroll types?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I wasn't able to find any events to hook into for this - I want to take control over the scroll distance when the user does things like moving the mouse wheel, clicking a scroll button (up or down), clicking the empty space of a scroll bar, etc.

For example, if I have a list of things, and each row is 16px tall, how would I be able to force it to scroll 16 pixels for single scroll events (i.e. mouse wheel up/down, or clicking the scroll button, if one exists)?  And then, if scrolling by clicking the empty scroll bar, how can I ensure it scrolls by a fixed amount, so when it's done scrolling, it would be perfectly aligned?  The best example I can give is how it behaves in Excel.  Provided you have the scroll lines to be set to 1 line in settings, scrolling up or down will move one row at a time.  Clicking the empty part of the scroll bar moves down exactly to the next not-fully-visible row.

My research, up until now, indicates I'll be using the `.scroll()` function (at least if I'm using jQuery), but I'm completely stumped at the plan of attack, even moreso because I'm unable to find any way to differentiate between a mouse wheel scroll, button scroll, or scrollbar jump (or whatever the terms would be).

Is there also a way to restrict this in CSS, avoiding any JavaScript at all?

Comment: Are you looking for [scroll-snap-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type)?

Comment: @DM Maybe?  It doesn't appear to do anything when I apply this to the appropriate div, and it just scrolls the same way it normally scrolls...

Comment: @DM It appears this only works for direct child elements, and unfortunately my list isn't a `<li>` element but rather a series of `<div>` elements that ended up being created in haste.  It appears this would work, but the elements I want to snap to are child elements of another child element within the scrollable div.  I'll have to look into it more if I really decide to sweat the small details.

Comment: Yeah this absolutely would work, albeit not for my implementation of the list.  I'd have to completely rework a few things and I can't be bothered.  Thank you so much for the heads up on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to use [scroll-snap-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type), as stated by [DM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14956277/d-m) in the comments.

You'd set the parent div to have `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;`, and it's immediate children elements would have `scroll-snap-align: top` (or bottom)!  This should allow rows to be viewed perfectly, provided the containing element is an appropriate size (and assuming each child element is a known fixed size).